# Removing ndiswrapper and inserting it back hangs OS after several times

Tags: ndiswrapper, modprobe

*sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper*

No matter how much time between commands. After 5-th or 6-th or 7-th iteration it hangs GUI. A also can not open another tty by Ctrl-Alt-F1,F2,... So I have to reboot.

I remove and insert ndiswrapper because it helps to reconnect wi-fi if it drops.

What makes my computer freeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is connected over wifi via ndiswrapper, removing it could certainly cause problems. If you insist on uninstalling ndiswrapper, you may want to disconnect your wireless connection and even remove the windows driver first. If your wifi drops there are many possible causes:

- too far from router
- outdated/unsupported driver
- modem configuration, interference in the building, any other cause that could interfere with wifi...

If your wifi drops, don't remove ndiswrapper. First try to reconnect, what happens? You could use the command `sudo ifconfig [wlan0] [down/up]` where `wlan` is your wireless adapter (could be wlan1, ra0...). Treat this as a wireless issue and troubleshoot it accordingly. It would help if you would post the chipset and windows driver you're using, that way device-specific troubleshooting steps could be looked at.

See more on wireless troubleshooting [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-troubleshoot-wireless-network-connection-in-ubuntu.html), [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/681149/ubuntu-wifi-troubleshoot), [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide), and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo).

Comment: _If your computer is connected over wifi via ndiswrapper, removing it could certainly cause problems._

Thank you man!
I couldn't imagine that unloading ndiswrapper module could make OS to crash. I was sure ndiswrapper handles such unhappy circumstances transparently. 

I give up unloading ndiswrapper, actually I give up ndiswrapper at all.

Comment: @zuba Well, sometimes you don't have a choice. Sometimes there is no native driver, and sometimes the native driver hasn't caught up yet to the windows driver. If `ndiswrapper` works (or at least works better than the native driver), it's a fairly amazing option to have.

Comment: Sure. I use rt73usb, rt2x00lib, rt2x00usb modules now